# What's the rationale for UTF-8 to store the code point directly?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, history

UTF-8 stores the significant bits of the code point in the low bits of the code units

```
U+0000-U+007F       0xxxxxxx
U+0080-U+07FF       110xxxxx    10xxxxxx
U+0800-U+FFFF       1110xxxx    10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx
U+10000-U+10FFFF    11110xxx    10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx
```

That requires the decoder to check for [over long sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Overlong_encodings) (like `C0 80` instead of `00`) and also reduces the number of code points encodable up to a fixed number of bytes. If it uses the same encoding but maps the code points like this

- First 128 code points (U+0000—U+007F): 1 byte
- Next 2048 code points (U+0080—U+087F): 2 bytes. E.g. `C0 81`: U+0081
- Next 65536 code points (U+0880—U+1087F): 3 bytes. E.g. `E0 B0 B1`: U+0881
- Next 131072 code points (U+10880—U+10FFFF, up to U+20880): 4 bytes. E.g. `F0 B0 B0 B1`: U+10881

(i.e. the value encodes the offset to the start of the range)

then many more characters can be encoded using a shorter sequence. Decoding is likely also faster, since it needs just an addition with a constant, which is often less costly than a branch to check for overly long code point. In fact 2048 more characters can be squeezed into 3 bytes if we remove the surrogate pair range from the mapping

So why is UTF-8 storing the code points that way?

Answer (score 1):

The rationale is well documented in the "placemat" anecdote which tells about how Ken Thompson and Rob Pike whipped up the spec on the placemat in a restaurant when the Unicode guys (actually somebody from X/Open) contacted them for a review of a draft specification.

http://doc.cat-v.org/bell_labs/utf-8_history contains a narrative by Rob Pike himself, with correspondence between him, Ken Thompson, and the X/Open people. It calls out this desideratum as one of the missing key pieces in the earlier draft:

> the ability to
>   synchronize a byte stream picked up mid-run, with less that one
>   character being consumed before synchronization

In other words, when you are looking at a byte whose high bit is set, you can tell from that byte value alone whether you are in the middle of a UTF-8 sequence, and if so, how far you need to rewind to get to the start of the multi-byte encoded character.

The full story is well worth a read, so I will just briefly summarize it here. The following is an abridged version of a section of the [Wikipedia article's history section.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#History)

> By early 1992, the search was on for a good byte-stream encoding of multi-byte character sets. The draft ISO 10646 standard contained a non-required annex called UTF-1 that provided a byte stream encoding of its 32-bit code points. This encoding was not satisfactory on performance grounds, among other problems, and the biggest problem was probably that it did not have a clear separation between ASCII and non-ASCII ...
>
> In July 1992, the X/Open committee XoJIG was looking for a better encoding. Dave Prosser of Unix System Laboratories submitted a proposal for one that had faster implementation characteristics and introduced the improvement that 7-bit ASCII characters would only represent themselves; all multi-byte sequences would include only bytes where the high bit was set. ...
>
> In August 1992, this proposal was circulated by an IBM X/Open representative to interested parties. A modification by Ken Thompson of the Plan 9 operating system group at Bell Labs made it somewhat less bit-efficient than the previous proposal but crucially allowed it to be self-synchronizing, letting a reader start anywhere and immediately detect byte sequence boundaries. It also abandoned the use of biases and instead added the rule that only the shortest possible encoding is allowed; the additional loss in compactness is relatively insignificant, but readers now have to look out for invalid encodings to avoid reliability and especially security issues. Thompson's design was outlined on September 2, 1992, on a placemat in a New Jersey diner with Rob Pike. In the following days, Pike and Thompson implemented it and updated Plan 9 to use it throughout, and then communicated their success back to X/Open, which accepted it as the specification for FSS-UTF.

Comment: I know about self-synchronization but I'm not asking about that. In fact my proposed encoding above is self-synchronizing just like UTF-8, just differ in the encoding of the code point in the low bits of each byte (offset instead of direct bits). I want to know why they didn't use the offset method which is much better

Comment: Maybe then edit your question to clarify; though I suspect the only possible answers are pure speculation unless you can get Ken Thompson himself to answer this.